# How to pass delegates as <T> parameter in function

Tags: c#, linq

```
public delegate bool CompareValue<in T1, in T2>(T1 val1, T2 val2);
    public static bool CompareTwoLists<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<T1> list1, IEnumerable<T2> list2, CompareValue<T1, T2> compareValue)
    {
        return list1.Select(item1 => list2.Any(item2 => compareValue(item1, item2))).All(search => search)
                && list2.Select(item2 => list1.Any(item1 => compareValue(item1, item2))).All(search => search);
    }
```

In the above function; how to pass "compareValue" as parameter while calling "CompareTwoLists" function?

Comment: Instead of defining your own type `CompareValue<T1, T2>`, you can just use `Func<T1, T2, bool>`.

Answer (score 1):

With a lambda expression that matches the delegate:

```
var people = new List<Person>();
var orders = new List<Order>();

bool result = CompareTwoLists(people, orders, 
    (person, order) => person.Id == order.PersonId);
```

Or as a reference to a method that matches the delegate:

```
static bool PersonMatchesOrder(Person person, Order order)
{
    return person.Id == order.PersonId;
}

bool result = CompareTwoLists(people, orders, PersonMatchesOrder);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method (Normal or Anonymous) that matches that delegate's signature. Below is a sample:

```
var list1 = new List<string>();
var list2 = new List<int>();

CompareValue<string, int> compareValues = (x, y) => true;

CompareTwoLists(list1, list2, compareValues);
```

You can also replace the anonymous method, with a normal method:

```
CompareValue<string, int> compareValues = SomeComparingMethod;

static bool SomeComparingMethod(string str, int number)
{
    // code here
}
```

### Another Approach

You can change your method to use `Func`:

```
public static bool CompareTwoLists<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<T1> list1, IEnumerable<T2> list2, 
                                           Func<T1, T2, bool> compareValue)
{
    return list1.All(x => list2.Any(y => compareValue(x, y)))
        && list2.All(x => list1.Any(y => compareValue(y, x)));
}
```

And Change the caller method to:

```
Func<User, Role, bool> compareValues = 
                            (u, r) => r.Active
                                   && u.Something == r.Something 
                                   && u.SomethingElse != r.SomethingElse);
```

Comment: Instead of using delegates; is it possible to use array? like below 'string[] Params = new string[] { "ProductCode", "ProductName" };'

Comment: @Pradu Instead of using the old-style Delegates, you can use Func. Check the edited answer.

Comment: @Pradu Also, check the updated code for method `CompareTwoLists` above in the second approach. `Select` is a projection that transforms each element, you don't need it in your case.

Comment: Is it possible to change ' Func<T1, T2, bool> compareValue ' to List<T> Expression? I need to pass list of column names to compare list instead of compareValues. If I pass only ProductName then only compare ProductName. If 'List<T> Expression'  have multiple names should compare with these all. Is it possible by using any binding expression?

Comment: @Pradu The code above doesn't restrict you to one Property comparison, You can write: `Func<User, Role, bool> compareValues = (u, r) => u.Something == r.Something && u.SomethingElse != r.SomethingElse && r.Active);` .. So you can specifiy any comparison you want based on 0-N Properties.

Comment: How to dynamically create this expression? 'compareValues = (u, r) => u.Something == r.Something && u.SomethingElse != r.SomethingElse && r.Active);' because am getting this compare values as array. I wanted to convert this Array items to Binding expression. if array have value like ProductName,ProductCode; then create a linq expression dynamically. 'compareValues = (u, r) => u.ProductName== r.ProductName&&'  u.ProductCode== r.ProductCode && etc..'

Comment: @Pradu Please specifiy a specific and complete example in your question. You didn't say anything about passing string properties in your question. Edit you question and provide a complete example !